# Connected subspace of the product of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Is it true that any connected set  of $X \times Y$ is of the form $A \times B$ where $A$ is connected  subset of $X$, and $B$ is a connected  subset of $Y$?

Comment: what are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: You can find lots of counterexamples in $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Is $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $A \times B$?

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, the L-shaped set in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ that is the union of the line segments
$[0,1]\times 0$ and $0\times[0,1]$ is not a product of sets in the component spaces.

However, the converse *is* true: the product of connected sets is connected.